# Facebook connect not redirecting after authentication WITHOUT javascript support

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to do a facebook connect but the problem is this needs to work **without** Javascript as it is on mobile. I have implemented the the PHP-SDK Api but the whole point of OAuth is that it gets a temporary token, then redirects you to the site(FB) to authenticate and only then redirects back which will give you your final token. Have implemented the Twitter OAuth without a problem, but Facebook tries to return me to my site with javascript on the uiserver.php file ... following link ui.

http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=163134400401544&next=http%3A%2F%2Fewn.christoff.lan%2Fusers%2Flogin&display=touch&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fewn.christoff.lan%2Fusers%2Flogin&return_session=1&session_version=3&fbconnect=1&canvas=0&legacy_return=1&method=permissions.request&_rdr

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Let us know if that changes things for you.

Comment: I've read through all the facebook documentation and no where do they talk about a javascript-less login. Everything works fine except for just before you are redirected back to your own site. I will go and have a look to confirm whether or not changing the APP in facebook itself or even upgrading the SDK helps and post my findings here...

Comment: Seems like this was just a bug in facebook API. This is now irrelevant as the API has been upgraded.